# How do i use openCV to stream 5 webcams simultanously with only 2 USB Ports?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

i need to use 5 Webcams at once to get real-time VDO streaming for my personal project . I already wrote my program with Python,OpenCV to handle multiple webcam with multi-threading but i am struggle to run 5 cameras at once because i only have 3 USB 3.0 ports available on my PC. i tried connecting all of them in a single USB 3.0 hub and it didn't work.

Is there anyway to work around with my limitation or do i really need to buy USB controller board for it ?

Here my code

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2,time

def update(capture,name):
    while True:
        if capture.isOpened():
            _,frame = capture.read()
            cv2.imshow(name,frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key == ord('x'):
                capture.release()
                cv2.destroyWindow(name)
                exit(1)
        time.sleep(.01)

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vid2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
vid3 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
vid4 = cv2.VideoCapture(3)
vid5 = cv2.VideoCapture(4)

cam1 = Thread(target=update,args=(vid,'Cam 1'))
cam2 = Thread(target=update,args=(vid2,'Cam 2'))
cam3 = Thread(target=update,args=(vid,'Cam 3'))
cam4 = Thread(target=update,args=(vid2,'Cam 4'))
cam5 = Thread(target=update,args=(vid,'Cam 5'))

cam1.start()
cam2.start()
cam3.start()
cam4.start()
cam5.start()
```

Comment: USB 3.0 should have enough bandwidth... do your cams stream uncompressed? you could run the cameras in modes that require less bandwidth, say set FOURCC to MJPEG -- and did you notice what `args=` you are passing to those threads? -- your code is also wrong. check isOpened **once** only, and **do not** say `_,frame = `, say `success, frame = ...` and `if not success: break` this is shown correctly in all the official opencv documentation, and wrongly everywhere else. you really should *not* trust random youtube tutorials. I haven't seen one that isn't made by someone incompetent.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yeah, it was my mistake . i didn't put my latest code in this . i already fix that and thank for the success, frame = ... bit . that could really help me terminated my program correctly . Also i found a solution. i just need to buy another USB 3.0 Hub . 2 webcams in each USB 3.0 Hub and 1 in USB 3.0 port should do the trick